# Why is $(x,z)$ not principal in $k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. I want to show $(x,z)$ is not principal in $R=k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ but I ran into some difficulties. I know $(xy-z^2)$ is prime and polynomials in $R$ are all of the for $c+dz$, where $c,d\in k[x,y]$. So I suppose $(x,z) = (a+bz)$ for some $a,b$. Then for some $g=g_1+g_2z$, $g(a+bz) = g_1 a +g_2bxy+(g_2a+g_2b)z = z$ and similarly for some $q=q_1+q_2z$, $q(a+bz) = q_1 a +q_2bxy+(q_2a+q_2b)z = x$. If $(x,z)$ is principal, this set of equations should give me a contradiction. But I struggled to see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $(x,z)$ is is principal, then its square is also principal. It follows that the ideal $(x,y,z)$ is principal. But the height of this ideal is 2, a contradiction.

Comment: @user26857 why would the square is principal imply (x,y,z) is principal? Elements of the square are $x^2,z^2=xy,xz....$ they don't seem to generate $x,y,z$.

Comment: What you wrote are generators of the square, not only *elements*, so the square is $x(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start, you wrote the equations down wrong. You should have the following:

$(a+bz)(g_1+g_2z)=g_1a+g_2bxy+(g_1b+g_2a)z=z$
$(a+bz)(q_1+q_2z)=q_1a+q_2bxy+(q_1b+q_2a)z=x$

So $g_1a+g_2bxy=0$, $g_1b+g_2a=1$, $q_1a+q_2bxy=x$, $q_1b+q_2a=0$. The last equation says $q_1=ac$ and $q_2=-bc$ for some $c\in k[x,y]$; plugging in to the third equation gives $a^2c-b^2cxy=x$, so $c|x$. If $c$ is constant, then from looking at the monomial with the highest power of $x$ inside the highest-degree terms of $a^2c$ and $b^2cxy$, the highest-degree term of $b^2cxy$ cannot cancel with the highest-degree term of $a^2c$. Therefore the degree of the LHS is at least two while the degree of the right hand side is one, a contradiction. So $c=ex$ for some nonzero constant $e$, giving $a^2ex-b^2ex^2y=x$ or $a^2e-b^2exy=1$.

Now look at the highest-degree terms of $a^2e$ and $b^2exy$ sorted by degree then exponent of $x$: these come from the corresponding highest-degree terms of $a$ and $b$, and the term from $a^2e$ has an even exponent in $x$ while the term from $b^2exy$ has an odd exponent in $x$, so they cannot cancel and if $b\neq 0$, then we have a term of degree 2 on the LHS but none on the RHS. This implies $b=0$, so $a$ is a unit, and $a+bz=a$ is homogeneous of degree zero, contradicting the fact that $(x,z)$ contains only homogeneous elements of positive degree.

(There are of course other ways to show this - the tangent space is a much cleaner way in my eyes: letting $m=(x,y,z)\subset R$, the image of $(x,z)$ in $m/m^2$ is a two-dimensional subspace, which cannot happen if $(x,z)$ were principal.)

Comment: Im sorry but I can't see why y|a^2 : (

Comment: @FungSanGaan fixed again, hopefully for the last time 

Comment: In the first paragraph the highest degree terms cannot cancel is because the even/odd of the multiplicity right? And also, why would this imply one of a,b is zero? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes - the monomial with the largest $x$-degree in the highest-degree portion of $a^2c$  will be of the form $x^{2i}y^{2j}$, but the monomial with the largest $x$-degree in the highest-degree portion of $b^2cxy$ will be of the form $x^{2k+1}y^{2l+1}$, and those cannot cancel out, so the degree of the LHS is at least 2 while the degree of the RHS is 1, contradiction. (See why I like the other way better?)